# What causes 1000Hz (and multiples) electromagnetic interference?

Tags: audio, emc, interference, emi-filtering

When recording old analog synthesizers (different brands and models) I'm getting interference in the audio. This started suddenly about two years ago (I thought the synth I was using was malfunctioning, had it serviced, and even bought another identical one, only to find the problem persisting.)

I'm used to old synths picking up a lot of 50Hz (and multiples) mains hum, but this signal is exactly 1000 Hz and all multiples, up to above 20kHz. It's about 60dB below the signal level and 12dB above the noise floor (see image). It's not there if I unplug the synth, so it's not being picked up by the cable or my audio interface.

I'm guessing some other appliance is creating this interference, but when it started I hadn't bought any new audio or computer equipment or household appliance. It could be something my neighbours are using, but I'd like to have some idea of what to look for.

So, **what kind of equipment or phenomenon could be causing interference at exactly 1000 Hz and multiples?** Is this a typical problem? It seems like a strange frequency for any kind of wifi or other communications signal.

[image: 440Hz note with 1000Hz interference indicated in yellow]

<sup>440Hz note with 1000Hz interference indicated in yellow</sup>

*(In case this is relevant, the synths used are two different Korg MS-20's, a Korg MS-10 and a Yamaha CS-15, all between 35 and 40 years old; one of the MS-20's was recently serviced and had parts like capacitors replaced. Service manuals with circuit diagrams and part lists for the Korg MS-20 and MS-10 and the Yamaha CS-15 can be found online.)*

Comment: Is your mobile phone anywhere near it? Or a device with a Wi-Fi card?

Comment: One more question, are you using a USB recording device?

Comment: @TomCarpenter the interference seems to be present whatever appliances I have near or not, switched on or not, whether my fridge or heater are switched on or not, in the summer winter, day, night... The only thing that's always on is my computer, screen and external usb audio interface. But I was using those before the interference started.

Comment: "external USB audio interface" --> [quite likely a culprit](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/33655/what-is-causing-a-cyclic-1khz-noise-signal-in-audio-recording)

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yes, an Edirol UA-25 (version 1). But I've been using that all along, before the interference started.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks for that link. The 1000 Hz indeed points to USB, apparently.

Comment: @YourUncleBob - Based on your info, consider this hypothesis (I'm not certain of it, so not suggesting it as an answer): Two years ago (when this noise started), *something* changed but it wasn't a *deliberate* change. The potential for a low-level 1kHz noise seems to always be there in your setup, as explained by the link kindly provided by *Tom*. Therefore the change two years ago, could have been a failure in whatever mechanism was *preventing* the (always present?) 1kHz noise from being injected into your analog audio. That might suggest shielding/grounding as something to investigate.

Comment: Exactly 1KHz sounds like the reference frequency for some phase-locked-loop.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf I think Tom identified the source, though. It's too close of a fit. USB uses a precise 1 ms timer for its work. And I think Sam identified the reason why the right direction about why it might not have been present earlier but shows up later.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks; I'll experiment with different cables and move the usb devices away from the synths, and see if that helps. I could also try version 2 of the Edirol UA-25 audio interface, which adds a ground lift switch.

Comment: @YourUncleBob - OK, and good luck with your investigation! I'm not an audio expert and, just to be clear, I'm not suggesting that (for example) moving USB devices away from the synths would be a "fix", even if it seems to work. Rather, I wanted to introduce the hypothesis that the change which started 2 years ago might *not* have been when the 1kHz source started operating. Instead, that could have been when the *suppression* of a (pre-existing) 1kHz noise source *failed* - and that may lead to considering different types (and locations) of problems e.g. damage to an existing cable.

Comment: [cont'd] It's going to be difficult to remember all the details from 2 years ago. However *something* clearly changed, since you say this started suddenly. If you can recall anything which *did* change (**no matter how apparently unrelated**), *immediately before* the noise started to be detected, then in my experience, that may give useful areas for investigation. This investigation of a "time correlation" is part of some successful troubleshooting methodologies, and can highlight odd causes (e.g. problem started after flooding of neighbours yard, where earthing rod is located!). Good luck!